# Gcloud no space error after editing prompt

Tags: google-cloud-shell

I was editing my bash prompt and I had to make a backup so i ran:

```
cp ~/.bashrc ~/.bashrc.bak
```

The next day I tried to download an `npm` package and it spat out:

```
npm ERR! code ENOSPC
npm ERR! syscall write
npm ERR! errno -28
npm ERR! nospc ENOSPC: no space left on device, write
npm ERR! nospc There appears to be insufficient space on your system to finish.
npm ERR! nospc Clear up some disk space and try again.
```

However I have not installed anything, So i  restored and deleted my backup of `.bashrc.bak`
and ran it again and it spat out the same thing only it did it 12 times.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

The Cloud shell is not designed to create a large development because this ephemeral VM has only [5GB of persistent disk](https://cloud.google.com/shell).

AS a workaround you can [reset Cloud shell](https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/resetting-cloud-shell#resetting) to purge all unnecessary data and start from the scratch with an empty disk

Or you can use a [Compute Engine](https://cloud.google.com/free) Always free `F1-micro` instance, these instances include 30 GB-months HDD